# Use of "which in part" - what grammar rule is involved?

Tags: grammar, esl

Can someone explain how this author uses "which in part" in this sentence? What grammar rule allows the author to use "which in part"? How can I too use "which in part" correctly in a sentence?

> The investment shows Amazon’s willing to stick its neck out for a food delivery company—and squashes concerns that Uber’s disappointing IPO (which in part hinged on the success of its Uber Eats service) would stifle food delivery hype.

Comment: Consider that it might be written "... which, in part, hinged ..."

Answer (score 3):

As per Hot Lick's comment, you could re-write the sentence as

> which, in part, hinged on the success...

In part is another way to phrase partially (i.e. not completely).

Thus, the phrase means that the success of the IPO hinged partially on the success of Uber Eats.